# Directive with ng-repeat and ngmodel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angular-directive

I created a directive to mount forms the app, do ngrepeat to get the information from the fields and set the template.

The problem is when I try to record the ngmodel the resource, I do not know how to do.

```
<field-create ng-repeat="field in grupo.fields" field="field" ng-model="item.grupos"></field-create>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('fieldCreate', function($compile, $timeout) {

    var inputtpl    = '<md-input-container><label>{{field.title}}</label><input ng-model="item.grupo.fields.model"></md-input-container>';
    var textareatpl = '<md-input-container><label>{{field.title}}</label><textarea ng-model="item.grupo.fields.model" columns="1" md-maxlength="300"></textarea></md-input-container>';
    var checkboxtpl = '<md-checkbox ng-model="item.grupo.fields.model">{{field.title}}</md-checkbox>';

    var getTemplate = function(fieldType) {
        var template = '';

        switch(fieldType) {
            case 'input':
                template = inputtpl;
                break;
            case 'textarea':
                template = textareatpl;
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
                template = checkboxtpl;
                break;
        }
        return template;
    }

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.html(getTemplate(scope.field.type));
        $timeout(function(){
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        });
    }

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: linker,
        scope: {
            field: '=',
            model: '=ngModel'
        }
    }

});
```

UPDATE:

I got a breakthrough, but due to repeat, is changed just a field, any field I change .. change the same model: /

[image]

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/S20jluwSyXncp74KyTn9?p=preview

UPDATED:
I managed to do What do I want, the solution is to use the KEY that creates formly as ngmodel.

Now the work consists in making a check for this field be unique, but can give problem.

Comment: Can you add a plunker example ?

Comment: @LucasRoselli http://plnkr.co/edit/S20jluwSyXncp74KyTn9?p=preview